# another unexpected token `fi' error

Tags: bash, debian

I am trying to test 7 days for specific conditions and need to account for leap years.  I think I have the logic right, been over it 100 times.  But for some reason I keep getting the same error.

```
:~$ bin/shabbat/test
bin/shabbat/test: line 90: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
bin/shabbat/test: line 90: `  fi'
```

Don't laugh to hard please.  I am not a programmer.  I have to copy/paste code that works and change it try to get it to do what I want it to do.

```
#!/bin/bash

STORDIR="${HOME}/bin/shabbat/data"
DAY=28
MONTH=1
YEAR=2016

# Calculate next day accounting for leap years
function Next_Day
{
    case ${ $MONTH } in
        1) 
        FULL="31"
        ;;
        2)
        FULL="28"
        ;;
        3)
        FULL="31"
        ;;
        4) 
        FULL="30"
        ;;
        5)
        FULL="31"
        ;;
        6)
        FULL="30"
        ;;
        7) 
        FULL="31"
        ;;
        8)
        FULL="31"
        ;;
        9)
        FULL="30"
        ;;
        10) 
        FULL="31"
        ;;
        11)
        FULL="30"
        ;;
        12)
        FULL="31"
        ;;
esac

if [[ "$DAY" -le "27" ]]; then
    (( DAY++ ))
    exit

elif [[ ${MONTH} == "2" ]]; then
    rem1=$((YEAR%4))
    rem2=$((YEAR%100))
    rem3=$((YEAR%400))

    if [ ${rem3} = "0" ]; then
        $FULL="29"
        exit
    fi

    if [ ${rem2} = "0" -a ${rem3} != "0" ]; then
      # echo "$YEAR Is Not A Leap Year"
        exit
    fi

    if [ ${rem1} = "0" -a ${rem2} != "0" ]; then
      # echo "$YEAR Is A Leap Year"
        $FULL="29"
    else
      # echo "$YEAR Is Not A Leap Year"
        exit
    fi

    if [ ${DAY} = ${FULL} -a ${MONTH} -lt "12" ]; then
        (( MONTH++ ))
        (( DAY++ ))
        exit
    fi

elif [ ${DAY} = ${FULL} -a ${MONTH} = "12" ]; then
    (( YEAR++ ))
    let MONTH=1
    let DAY=1
    exit  
fi
exit
fi
}

################# 
# # Main Code # #
#################

for (( i = 1; i < 7; i++)); do

    YOMTOVE=$(hdate -dhq $DAY $MONTH $YEAR | awk 'NR==3')
    echo "$YOMTOVE"
    if [[ -n "$YOMTOVE" ]]; then
        grep ^"$YOMTOVE" "$STORDIR"/YomTove.cvs
    # actions based on what holiday it is
    fi
done
Next_Day

exit
```

I have only gotten this far with help from my local lug and linuxquestion.org but I hate to keep bugging them with my old brain problems.

Thanks.

Comment: what's this `${ $MONTH }` thing? Just use `$MONTH`

Comment: As you can see with the fixed indentation, you have an extra `fi` that doesn't match an `if`.

Comment: I suggest you replace that `case` statement with an array containing the lengths of each month.

Comment: Or at least fold the case statement up to 12 lines, no need for 36 lines. AND statements like `$FULL="29"` (with the leading `$`) are not going to do what you intend. AND `$DAY -le 27, then DAY++;exit` ??? Os that debug code? Very confusing, but ... Good luck!

Comment: Also you can collapse cases with the same outcome, `case $MONTH in [13578] | 1[02] ) FULL=31;;`...

Comment: Thanks for fixing the indentation Barmar

Comment: tripleee, I don't understand what that is doing.  Mostly the " | 1[2] " part

Comment: think I figured it out, that is for 12 :)

Comment: shellter, if DAY = 28 that "maybe" a FULL month but 27 is never a FULL month so DAY++  then it will fall through to the leap year checks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either want to remove line 88 or line 90, they are unmatched `fi`s. I am guessing you need to remove line 90.

Also I think you need to replace `case ${ $MONTH } in` with `case ${MONTH} in`

Comment: Thanks texasflood.  I actually think it is line 81 that needs deleting.  The elif on 83 is part of the checks for a leap year.

Comment: Ok, well in that case the indentation is confusing, the elif should be at the same level as the if above it

Comment: there is a missing leap year conditional check.  Should be something like if (( DAY < FULL )); then
 (( DAY++ ))
 exit